# jquery click handler fires multipli times

Tags: jquery, events, click, handler

Im having trouble that my saveBtn click events fire multipli times because the function below is called and registering a new click handler for each time the user calls the function. How do i only register one click event handler?

```
function forceAnnotation(annotationNo,objectNo,clientNo, callBack) {

     $('#forcedAnnotation').dialog( { 
        modal: true,
        width: 385,
        height: 370,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        open: function(event, ui) { jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide(); }
     });

     $('#cancelBtn').click(function() {
        callBack.onCancel();
        $('#forcedAnnotation').dialog("close")
     });

     $('#saveBtn').click(function(){
             //make ajax call
     });

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use the jQuery.one() function.

"Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element."

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Thx, I had the same problem for modal dialog box. When I opened a new dialog box, even if the last one was closed, the click event was still active on both, so use one() dit the trick : `one('click')` instead of `on('click')`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are forced to add the click handler every time why not just detach it every time also with:

```
$('#cancelBtn').unbind('click');
```

To make sure you just unbind this specific click handler you can use namespaces.

```
$('#cancelBtn').unbind('click.annotation').bind('click.annotation', function(e) {
  callBack.onCancel();
  $('#forcedAnnotation').dialog("close")
});

$('#saveBtn').unbind('click.annotation').bind('click.annotation', function(e) {
  //make ajax call
});
```

This should work, I hope

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to refactor your code to remove the `click` handler registration to be outside of the function.

If that is not possible, you could declare the cancel function outside of the scope of your `forceAnnotation()` function. And in your function redefine it to be what you need.

```
 var cancelClick = function(){};

 function forceAnnotation(annotationNo,objectNo,clientNo, callBack) {

   $('#forcedAnnotation').dialog( { 
    modal: true,
    width: 385,
    height: 370,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) { jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide(); }
   });

   cancelClick =  function(){
                  callBack.onCancel();
                  $('#forcedAnnotation').dialog("close");
                }
 }


 $('#cancelBtn').click(function() {
   cancelClick();
 });

 $('#saveBtn').click(function(){
         //make ajax call
 });
```

Other options are, [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

> Attach a handler to an event for the
>   elements. The handler is executed at
>   most once per element.

Or to simply [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the click handler each time.

```
 $('#cancelBtn').unbind("click").click(function() {
    callBack.onCancel();
    $('#forcedAnnotation').dialog("close")
 });
```